What’s the part of the soul that enjoys existing and is that the part that has to get punished if it sins?
BH
Hi,
I heard that there is a part of the soul of man that enjoys simply existing is this the level of the Nefesh Elokit?
If yes which part is it of the Nefesh Ruach Neshama Chaya Or Yichida of the Nefesh Elokit that is enjoying simply existing?
And what ever of those parts it is, is this also the part of the soul that has to be judged together with the body of man if it sins as in the debate between Rebbi and Antoninus in Sanhedrin 91a-b?
And if it’s one of the lower levels that enjoys simply existing and not the higher like the levels like of Chaya and Yechida shouldn’t there no punishment on account of those levels that didn’t sin since they are completely connected with Hashem and united with him?
